# HTML Canvas - Draw vertically cropped text

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a Canvas where I'm drawing some things in 2D, one of the elements is a text that has to be vertically cropped. I cannot draw the whole text and crop it after as there are already some elements drawn and they would be lost.

I've been checking the [MDN Canvas docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) but I haven't found a way of implementing this feature.

Would it be possible to make this in vanilla JS, if so how should I proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may draw your contents to another canvas and then copy to original canvas with drawImage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: I didn't think about that, I like the simple approach. I'll gonna work with that at the moment. Thanks!!